# How can I write a Trait in Julia with open-ended types?

Tags: generics, julia, abstraction, traits

This is an attempt to simplify one part of the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614353/how-can-i-dispatch-on-traits-relating-two-types-where-the-second-type-that-co-s):

I want to write some code that is guaranteed to work on types that meet certain criteria. Let's say today I write some code:

```
immutable Example
    whatever::ASCIIString
end
function step_one(x::Example)
    length(x.whatever)
end
function step_two(x::Int64)
    (x * 2.5)::Float64
end
function combine_two_steps{X}(x::X)
    middle = step_one(x)
    result = step_two(middle)
    result
end
x = Example("Hi!")
combine_two_steps(x)
```

Running this works:

```
julia> x = Example("Hi!")
Example("Hi!")

julia> combine_two_steps(x)
7.5
```

Then another day I write some more code:

```
immutable TotallyDifferentExample
    whatever::Bool
end
function step_one(x::TotallyDifferentExample)
    if x.whatever
        "Hurray"
    else
        "Boo"
    end
end
function step_two(x::ASCIIString)
    (Int64(Char(x[end])) * 1.5)::Float64
end
```

And what do you know, my generic combine function still works!

```
julia> y = TotallyDifferentExample(false)
TotallyDifferentExample(false)

julia> combine_two_steps(y)
166.5
```

Hurray! But, say it's a late night and I'm trying to do this AGAIN on a third example. I remember to implement `step_one`, but I forget to implement `step_two`!

```
immutable ForgetfulExample
    whatever::Float64
end
function step_one(x::ForgetfulExample)
    x.whatever+1.0
end
```

Now when I run this, I'm going to get a run-time error!

```
julia> z = ForgetfulExample(1.0)
ForgetfulExample(1.0)

julia> combine_two_steps(z)
ERROR: MethodError: `step_two` has no method matching step_two(::Float64)
```

Now, I work for a manager who will KILL ME if I ever get a run-time error. So what I need to do to save my life is to write a Trait that essentially says "if the type implements this trait, then it's safe to call `combine_two_steps`."

I want to write something like

```
using Traits
@traitdef ImplementsBothSteps{X} begin
    step_one(X) -> Y
    step_two(Y) -> Float64
end
function combine_two_steps{X;ImplementsBothSteps{X}}(x::X)
    middle = step_one(x)
    result = step_two(middle)
    result
end
```

b/c then I'd know that *if* `combine_two_steps` is ever *dispatched*, then it *will* run without raising an error that these methods don't exist.

Equivalently, `istrait(ImplementsBothSteps{X})` (being true) is equivalent to `combine_two_steps` will run without error-from-nonexistence-of-required-methods.

But, as everybody knows, I can't use that trait definition, because `Y` has no meaning. (In fact, oddly enough the code compiles without error,

```
julia> @traitdef ImplementsBothSteps{X} begin
           step_one(X) -> Y
           step_two(Y) -> Float64
       end

julia> immutable Example
           whatever::ASCIIString
       end

julia> function step_one(x::Example)
           length(x.whatever)::Int64
       end
step_one (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function step_two(x::Int64)
           (x * 2.5)::Float64
       end
step_two (generic function with 1 method)

julia> istrait(ImplementsBothSteps{Example})
false
```

but the types don't satisfy the trait even though the methods exist for some `Y`.) My first thought is I can change `Y` to something like `Any`

```
using Traits
@traitdef ImplementsBothSteps{X} begin
    step_one(X) -> Any
    step_two(Any) -> Float64
end
```

but this fails too b/c the `Any` really is supposed to be something like `Some`, not literally the `Any` type (since I never implemented a method `step_two` that could take any type as input), but some particular type that's shared across both lines!

So, the question is: what would you do in this situation? You want to pass around a "spec" (here in the form of the contract expressed by the Trait) such that any programmer anywhere who meets the spec is guaranteed to be able to use your function `combine_two_steps`, but the spec essentially has an existential quantifier in its definition.

Is there a workaround? A better approach to writing the "spec" (e.g. "Don't use Traits, use something else"?) Etc.

By the way, it may sound contrived, but the above-linked question and this question are coming up regularly in a project I'm working on. I'm essentially stuck at a roadblock caused by this problem and have ugly workarounds that work case-by-case, but no approach to the general case.

Answer (score 2):

Generalizing on the suggestion in my question of using `Any` actually can work also, although it's ugly and doesn't really get to the point. Suppose you have already implemented methods

```
step_one(X) -> Y
step_two(Y) -> Z
```

Then you can write the trait as

```
@traitdef implements_both_steps begin
    step_one(X) -> Any
    step_two(Any) -> Z
end
```

And just add a dummy method

```
function step_two(x::Any)
    typeof(x)==Y ? step_two(x::Y) : error("Invalid type")
end
```

This can be wrapped up in a macro as well to save on repeating the pattern, and then once that method is implemented the trait is satisfied. It's a hack that I've been using (and that works) b/c it's fairly straightforward, but the solution is not in the spirit of my question.

Comment: Can you please post the details.

Answer (score 1):

Is this satisfactory:

```
@traitdef ImplementsStep2{Y} begin
    step_two(Y) -> Float64
end

# consider replacing `any` with `all`
@traitdef AnotherImplementsBothSteps{X} begin
    step_one(X)
    @constraints begin
        any([istrait(ImplementsStep2{Y}) for Y in Base.return_types(step_one,(X,))])
    end
end
```

With these trait definitions we have:

```
julia> istrait(ImplementsStep2{Int64})
true

julia> istrait(AnotherImplementsBothSteps{Example})
true
```

The trick is to use `@constraints` to basically do the non-straightforward stuff. And to use `Base.return_types` to get at the return types for a method. Admittedly this is a bit of a hack, but this is what my digging came up with. Perhaps a future version of `Traits.jl` will have better tools for this.

I've used `any` in the trait definition. This is a bit lax. Using `all` may be stricter but represent the constraint better, depending on what level of compile-time checking is desired.

Of course, Julia's good introspection and `try ... catch` allows doing all this checking at run-time.

Comment: The strategy of using Base.return_types is interesting. You've effectively written code that reflectively implements the "existential quantifier" step. I like this. I'm going to think about it a little more. This whole thing could be wrapped up into a "meta" macro, in fact, to make the process simpler to the end user. I want to investigate the performance of this strategy though. Do you know off the top of your head if this will cause method dispatch on traits to take a performance hit?

Comment: If the compiler can infer the types of the parameters while compiling, there should not be a performance hit (except for the initial generation and compilation of the functions involved). On the other hand, if the types are unknown, it could possibly be a performance hit to infer the right function, but the generated function is cached, so hopefully, this would still be done once. This is the usual story in Julia, when types are stable and inferred, top performance is achieved (BTW a big upvote for `mauro3` who wrote `Traits.jl`).

Comment: The methods used by `Traits.jl` are explained in the `README.md` of the github repo quite in depth (Link: https://github.com/mauro3/Traits.jl)